# How to identify the process locking a file?

Tags: process

I want to know the exact process that is using the lock file. I don't want to *fix* it, but just to know what is my system doing. How can I find out?

For example, this message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Again, I just want to identify the process using it, **not** how to fix it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is the infamous `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
aptitude 4974 root    3uW  REG   8,23        0 815673 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

In this case aptitude is using the file. You should use root in case you are not sure which user is locking the file. It's useful for a bunch of things too, sadly it doesn't come installed with Ubuntu, so you have to install it first.

For the rest of mortals, there's the `fuser` command. This is peculiar since it only returns the PID instead of the name of the process:

```
➜  ~  sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock
/var/lib/dpkg/lock:   4974
```

Here it says that the file and PID, which is 4974, so we must investigate who is:

```
➜  ~  ps 4974
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 4974 pts/1    Sl+    0:06 aptitude
```

Comment: Why is `lsof` infamous? Are there some problems with it?

Comment: @Ruslan Yeah, it allows clueless users know the actual usage of the systems contrary to what the sysadmins wants...

Comment: @Braiam Too much information can be a dangerous thing, in the right hands? ^-_-^

Comment: Second option in one line: `ps $(sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock)`

Answer (score 11):

lslocks is a simple way to do that.

```
lslocks |grep /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

For use shell to handle the process id:

```
for pid in `lslocks -rn | grep /var/lib/dpkg/lock|awk '{print $2}'`;
do 
    echo $pid; 
done
```

Comment: Yes. `lslocks` is the best way to go about it. Using `lsof` gave me this error: "lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs  Output information may be incomplete"

Comment: @Nav that's not an error, but a WARNING.