# /var/lib/dpkg/lock.....help!

Tags: dpkg

I had to reinstall the entire OS a little while ago and I have been trying to reinstall all of the programs I had before but I got a bit a of a problem now. I was trying to download `dropbox` from synaptic but it cannot finish the process and as a result I cannot update anything anymore. The line that comes out is:

```
  E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
  E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo apt-get -f update
sudo dpkg --clear-selections
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But nothing seems to work.

So is there a way to solve this??

Thanks

Comment: try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407605/how-to-identify-the-process-locking-a-file) in order to view who locks your file.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process do a search for the error message first. You have something else, like the software centre open.

Comment: Make sure all package managers are closed (synaptic, software center). This also happens if you cut the system off as it is installing a program (eg close a terminal that is still busy) did you do this, if so which package was installing at the time

Answer (score 0):

This command should find, identify and kill the proses that has locked dpkg

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following commands to remove or install an application.

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get autoremove

apt-get remove --purge packagename
```

you can check this post for [completely remove an application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)