# Cannot obtain lock in Kubuntu

Tags: upgrade, updates, kubuntu, discover-software-center

When ever I connect with the Wi-Fi, it asks wallet password. Is that holding the lock resource? Or should I update from the terminal? The actual error is shown at the bottom of the picture.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41709/387374

I went through this  link, but I don't want to mess up with the OS.

Can any buddy help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the process locking a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407605/how-to-identify-the-process-locking-a-file). Wallet password is completely UNRELATED to a dpkg lock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)