# Can't remove virtualbox using 'sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-6.0'

Tags: 18.04, apt, virtualbox

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
virtualbox-6.0*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another 
process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.38) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another 
process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
Setting up docker.io (18.09.7-0ubuntu1~18.04.4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another 
process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
installed docker.io package post-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 1
Setting up mdadm (4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another 
process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mdadm (--configure):
installed mdadm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
Setting up bridge-utils (1.5-15ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another 
process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package bridge-utils (--configure):
installed bridge-utils package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-fan:
ubuntu-fan depends on bridge-utils; however:
Package bridge-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-fan (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
Errors were encountered while processing:
libpam-systemd:amd64
docker.io
mdadm
bridge-utils
ubuntu-fan
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Message given after command is ran

Ubuntu version 18.04

My lslocks:

```
`COMMAND           PID  TYPE SIZE MODE  M      START        END PATH
 blkmapd           540 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
 thermald         1295 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
 usbmuxd          2399 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
 teams            2123 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0 1073741825 1073741825 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
 chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
 update-notifier 26233 FLOCK   0B WRITE 0          0          0 
/run/user/1000/up
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0 1073741824 1073742335 
containerd       1532 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 
gnome-shell      1847 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 
/run/user/121...
whoopsie         6406 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 
/run/lock...
teams           16728 POSIX      READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 
teams           16728 POSIX      READ  0        128        128 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
lvmetad           545 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0 1073741824 1073742335 
cron             1275 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
systemd-timesyn  1125 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
rpcbind          1124 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 /run...
frontend         8054 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 
frontend         8054 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 
frontend         8054 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 
teams            2123 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0          0          0 
chrome           5478 POSIX      READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0 1073741824 1073742335 
chrome           5478 POSIX      WRITE 0 1073741824 1073742335 
teams            2123 POSIX      READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 
teams            2123 POSIX      WRITE 0 1073741825 1073741825
```

`

Comment: It looks like apt is running and has locked all its resources until it's finished. Probably a daily update. Try again. I disable automatic updates for this very reason. Not for everyone, but ...

Comment: Trying again gives me the same error code

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl disable update-manager` and then reboot. Then try your purge again.

Comment: When try to disable the update manager I get the following - 'Failed to disable unit: Unit file update-manager.service does not exist.'

Comment: Did you reboot? What is the output of `lslocks`

Comment: Tried the reboot but that hasn't seemed to work

Comment: Hm. Ah a stale lock. Does this help https://askubuntu.com/questions/407605/how-to-identify-the-process-locking-a-file

Comment: I get the following `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t - This fixed the issue